# Exception with MySqlConnector and NLog

Tags: c#, .net-core, nlog, mysql-connector

I am trying to get @[Bradley Grainger] 's excellent MySqlConnector hooked up to an Nlog logger using dotnet core 3.0 - need the async abilities of MySqlConnector.

It has been running OK with MySql.Data, however performance is much better with MySqlConnector.  The web app runs fine with no NLog logger attached, however I get an exception when I try to use the logger, as per the instructions.

I have created a basic web api, (from the VS template) & do nothing more than trying to attach to the logger and then open a connection.

packages:

- MySqlConnector 0.60.2
- MySqlConnector.Logging.NLog 0.58.0
- NLog.Web.AspNetCore 4.9.0

nlog.config contains:

```xml
    <target name="database" xsi:type="Database" >
      <connectionString>${gdc:item=connectionString}</connectionString>
      <commandText>
        insert into log (
...
```

Program.cs gets the connection string and sets this for NLog:

```
DotEnv.Config();
string connectionString = "server=" + Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SQL_HOST") ...
GlobalDiagnosticsContext.Set("connectionString", connectionString);
```

When I add `MySqlConnectorLogManager.Provider = new NLogLoggerProvider();` to Startup.cs as per readme and get to the .Open() method

```
var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
connection.Open();
```

the following exception is thrown

```
System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection' threw an exception.'

Inner Exception:
FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.

  StackTrace:
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.SetState(ConnectionState newState) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlConnection.cs:line 668
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.<OpenAsync>d__26.MoveNext() in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlConnection.cs:line 292
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open() in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlConnection.cs:line 280
   at WebApplication1.DataReaderHelper.ExecuteStoredProcedure(String procedureName)
```

any ideas please?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the `<dbProvider>` for the Database target.

e.g.

```xml
 <target name="database" xsi:type="Database" 
      dbProvider="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection, MySql.Data" >
```

More examples are [on the NLog Wiki](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Database-target#dbprovider-examples)

Comment: The wiki example is only for the MySql.Data connector - however it prompted me to try:

`<target name="database" xsi:type="Database" 
            dbProvider="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection, MySqlConnector" >`
which does work, thanks

Comment: Please add the example to the wiki. It's publicly editable :)